# Strange things with c++ string input

Tags: c++, c++11

```
#include <iostream>
#include <cstring>
using namespace std;

const int BUFFER_SIZE = 80;

void getstr(char* &str);    

int main()
{
    char* str;
    while(true)
    {
        getstr(str);
        if (!strlen(str))
            break;
    }
    delete [] str;
    return 0;
}

void getstr(char* &str)
{
    char temp[BUFFER_SIZE];
    cout<<"Enter a string(empty line to quit): ";
    cin.get(temp, BUFFER_SIZE);
    while(cin.get()!='\n')
        continue;
    str = new char [strlen(temp)+1];
    strcpy(str, temp);
}
```

I have a string reading loop above and entering an empty line to terminate the loop doesn't work(after entering an empty line program stops responding to any input). But when I replace a loop in getstr with single cin.get() all works fine. What's wrong?

Comment: Why C-strings? Why not `std::string` and `std::getline()`? Or `std::cin.getline()` for that matter if you insist on C-strings? I also don't see the addition of a null character to terminate your C-string.

Comment: I want loop to discard newline character or redundant input if it is too long

Comment: Step through the program with the debugger that came with your development environment and keep an eye out for where the program does something you didn't expect.

Comment: @alex `std::getline()` discards the `\n` for you. `std::string` avoids size issues altogether.

Answer (score 1):

[`istream::get()`](http://www.cplusplus.com/reference/istream/istream/get/) sets `failbit` when empty string is read.

This makes `cin.get()` return `EOF` and this because you couldn't break the loop `while(cin.get()!='\n')`.

You can use [`ios::clear()`](http://www.cplusplus.com/reference/ios/ios/clear/) to clear `failbit`.

```
    cin.get(temp, BUFFER_SIZE);
    cin.clear(); // add this
    while(cin.get()!='\n')
        continue;
```

Answer (score 1):

> `cin.get(char* s, size_t n)` Extracts characters from the stream and stores them in s as a c-string, until either (n-1) characters have been extracted or the delimiting character is encountered: the delimiting character being either the newline character ('\n') or delim (if this argument is specified).
> The delimiting character is not extracted from the input sequence if found and remains there as the next character to be extracted from the stream (see getline for an alternative that does discard the delimiting character).
> A null character ('\0') is automatically appended to the written sequence if n is greater than zero, even if an empty string is extracted.

So here is the problem. `cin.get()` need to read at least 1 character. You can close stdin by pressing Ctrl+D and Enter, after that, your program will be finished.

And BTW, you are using `new` N times, but you have only 1 delete. You need to delete the previous buffer

Answer (score 0):

If you are going to use C++, you should really use cin/cout in an objectively consistent manner. For example:

```
string name;
cout << "What is your name: ";
getline (cin, name);
cout << "Your name is: " << name;
```

What you are doing is kind of a C/C++ hybrid (char arrays in leu of string objects, but using `std` namespace).

Now, I know this isn't your question, but what you are doing right now is slightly unorthodox which makes answering your question a bit difficult without putting the code in to and editor and debugging it.

Answer (score 0):

Given the c++11 tag, I assume that you really want C++ code. The great thing is that C++ simplifies this a lot.

```cpp
#include <iostream>
#include <string>

int main()
{
    std::string str;
    while(std::getline(std::cin, str) && !str.empty())
    {
        // do stuff
    }

    return 0;
}
```

Comment: Even simpler: `while(std::getline(std::cin, str) && !str.empty()) { ... }`  Don't ignore `cin`'s updated state after calling `getline`